# Symfony and Lucene

Tags: php, mysql, search, lucene, symfony1

**SOLVED**

See my answer below. Question left unchanged for anyone else who has trouble with this.

---

I'd like to use lucene (or anything else that could be used withs symfony for searching really) however I can't get the sfLucene plugin to work (says there are no tasks in the namespace "lucene" when i do ./symfony lucene:initialize). What can I do to get this to work or replace lucene?

symfony info:

```
chris@linux-9r49:~/Coding/PHP/cpn> ./sf -V
symfony version 1.3.0-BETA1 (/home/chris/Coding/PHP/cpn/lib/vendor/symfony/lib)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, no need to add 'solved' to the top of the question, you can tick your own answer to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: When I found the answer the question was too new to accept my own solution and I sort of forgot about it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me I didn't enable the plugin :P. For anyone else who has the problem open

```
projectfolder/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php
```

and change it so it says something like this:

```
 $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrinePlugin', 'sfLucenePlugin');
```

Then do

```
./symfony cc
./symfony lucene:initialize appnamehere
```